# xsl grouping by xml element for repetitive nodes in xslt1 into html table output

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xsl-grouping

I have a complex xml structure that looks like :

```
  <Items>
      <Item>
          <ItemTexts>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type1</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description11</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>1</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type1</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description12</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>2</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type2</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description21</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>3</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type2</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description22</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>4</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
          </ItemTexts>
         </Item>
    <Item>
          <ItemTexts>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type1</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description11</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>1</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type1</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description12</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>2</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type2</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description21</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>3</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type2</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description22</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>4</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
          </ItemTexts>
         </Item>
<Item>
          <ItemTexts>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type1</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description11</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>1</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type1</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description12</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>2</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type2</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description21</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>3</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type2</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description22</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>4</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
          </ItemTexts>
         </Item>
    <Item>
          <ItemTexts>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type3</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description31</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>1</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type3</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description32</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>2</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type2</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description21</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>3</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
            <ItemText>
              <ItemTextsType>type2</ItemTextsType>
              <ItemTextsTypeDesc>description22</ItemTextsTypeDesc>
              <ItemTextsLine>4</ItemTextsLine>
            </ItemText>
          </ItemTexts>
         </Item>
    </Items>
```

Each `<Item>` has MANY more xml elements , but I won't specify them now.

I run with xsl on each Item like :

```
<xsl:for-each select="Items/Item">
```

and I produce table with rows for each `<Item>` and many `<td>` in each row.

I need an example of how to group `<ItemText>` by `<ItemTextsType>` individually for each `<Item>` .

I will arrange the outcome in a table like :

```
 <table>
    <%--tr for each Item in Items--%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            some value from xml element according <b> Item1 </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            some more value from xml element according <b> Item1 </b>
        </td>
        <%--
        .
        .
        .
--%>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" dir="ltr">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="background-color: #507CD1; text-align: center">
                        <td colspan="3" style="font: bold; color: white">
                            Item1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; font: bold; color: #507CD1;">
                            type1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            description11
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            description12
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; font: bold; color: #507CD1;">
                            type2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            description21
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            description22
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            even more value from xml element according <b> Item1 </b>
        </td>
        <%--
        .
        .
        .
        --%>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>
            some value from xml element according <b> Item2 </b>
        </td>
        <td>
            some more value from  xml element according <b> Item2 </b>
        </td>
        <%--
        .
        .
        .
--%>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" dir="ltr">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="background-color: #507CD1; text-align: center">
                        <td colspan="3" style="font: bold; color: white">
                            Item2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; font: bold; color: #507CD1;">
                            type1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            description11
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            description12
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; font: bold; color: #507CD1;">
                            type2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            description21
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            description22
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            even more value from according <b> Item2 </b>
        </td>
        <%--
        .
        .
        .
        --%>
    </tr>
   <%-- and so on--%>
</table>
```

The point is that there is separate grouping for each `<Item>` into it's own `<tr><td><table>`  and inside that `<table>` there is groupping by `<ItemTextsType>`

I have tried something like

```
<xsl:key name="item-texts-type" match="ItemText" use="ItemTextsType" />


<xsl:for-each select="ItemTexts/ItemText[count(. | key('item-texts-type', ItemTextsType)[1]) = 1]">

                        <xsl:sort select="ItemTextsType" />
                        <tr>
                          <td style ="height:35px;font: bold; color:#507CD1;">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ItemTextsType" />
                          </td>
                        </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="key('item-texts-type', ItemTextsType)">
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                               <xsl:value-of select="ItemTextsTypeDesc" />
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>


                      </xsl:for-each>
```

but it only work on **non** repetitive nodes (if there were only one `<Item>`it would work fine).
**I can't change xml because it comes from customer .**

Please help me , I need it ASAP .

Thank you !!!!

Comment: What's the difference between this and your [previous seemingly identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374401/xsl-grouping-of-repetitive-nodes-by-xml-element-in-xslt1)?  I didn't notice that one until I'd answered this, and I seem to have independently come up with the same solution as the previous accepted answer.

Comment: Initially I gave example of needed output and ABach kindly answered it .But then I realized that my needed output is different from what I wrote before , so I changed it.Then I decided to open another question , so maybe the previous question will help somebody . I was hoping to return the old question to state before I edited it,but I couldn't so far - I'm a newbie in Stackoverflow...

Comment: If you go to the edit history for the original question you should see a "rollback" option against each revision number that you can use to roll the question back to that revision.

Comment: Thanks , edited the question so it would match the answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a separate grouping for each `Item` then one way to achieve that would be to include some unique identifier for the containing `Item` as part of the key value, e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="item-texts-type" match="ItemText"
         use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::Item), '|', ItemTextsType)" />

<!-- assuming the context node is the current Item -->
<xsl:variable name="currentItemId" select="generate-id()" />

<xsl:for-each select="ItemTexts/ItemText[count(. | key('item-texts-type',
        concat($currentItemId, '|', ItemTextsType))[1]) = 1]">
  <!-- .... -->
  <xsl:for-each select="key('item-texts-type',
        concat($currentItemId, '|', ItemTextsType))">
```

This would be much more straightforward if you could use XSLT 2.0 of course...