# XSL Grouping nodes by multiple similar siblings with multiple similar unknown values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Ok I am trying to build a table, But I'm not doing this correctly, I have no XSL example as nothing I tried came close to what I need.
(I have tried using xsl:apply-templates loops, even with modes, and even xsl:for-each and key() but cannot get the right filters.

Here is an example of the XML I would be using.
(the real xml I am using is more complex then this one below)

```
<report>
 <item>
  <vertical>
   <component>
    <partname>Left Side</partname>
    <parttype>Side</parttype>
    <partlocation>Outside</partlocation>
    <material>Wood</material>
    <thickness>20mm</thickness>
    <colour>White</colour>
   </component>
  </vertical>
  <vertical>
   <component>
    <partname>Right Side</partname>
    <parttype>Side</parttype>
    <partlocation>Outside</partlocation>
    <material>Wood</material>
    <thickness>20mm</thickness>
    <colour>White</colour>
   </component>
  </vertical>
  <vertical>
   <component>
    <partname>Back</partname>
    <parttype>Back</parttype>
    <partlocation>Inside</partlocation>
    <material>Plastic</material>
    <thickness>3mm</thickness>
    <colour>Black</colour>
   </component>
  </vertical>
 </item>
</report>
```

So the task I am wanting to do is, for-each `<item>` I need to start making a table, and inside that table I need to assess each `<component>` to find how many have the same `<material>`, `<thickness>` and `<colour>`.
Then I need to list the Material name and details.
Next I need all the `<components>` that have the same `<parttypes>` and `<partlocation>` that are of the same `<material>`, `<thickness>` and `<colour>`, to show their `<partname>` in a row for each one.
There is no fixed amount of materials I can expect, one time I might get 1, another time I could get 3. And I wont always know what values the nodes will contain.
Also in each `<item>` I can have 1-3 different `<parttype>` and `<partlocation>` (althought they work in pairs - and I know what the values of those nodes will be)

Here is a sample of the formatted finish given the really simple above code...

```
Wood, 20mm, White
Left Side
Right Side

Plastic, 3mm, Black
Back
```

this question is VERY similar, but not quite...
[xsl grouping of repetitive nodes by xml element in xslt1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374401/xsl-grouping-of-repetitive-nodes-by-xml-element-in-xslt1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use this key based solution as a first idea:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <!-- Define keys -->
    <xsl:key name="kmaterial" match="component" 
             use="concat (generate-id(../..), '|', material, '|', thickness, '|', colour)"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:for-each 
               select="vertical/component[
                    generate-id(.) = 
                    generate-id(key('kmaterial',   concat (generate-id(../..), '|', material, '|', thickness, '|', colour) )[1])  ]">

            <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="material"/>, <xsl:value-of select="thickness"/> , <xsl:value-of select="colour"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each
                         select="key('kmaterial',   concat (generate-id(../..), '|', $this/material, '|', $this/thickness, '|', $this/colour) )" >
                <xsl:value-of select="partname"/>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the following output:

```
Wood, 20mm , White
Left Side
Right Side
Plastic, 3mm , Black
Back
```

Comment: Thanks for the input hr_117, I have been playing around with this suggestion in my actual file to see if I can make it do what is required, but I fear it might only be half of the task.

Comment: To group also (next step) by `parttypes` and `partlocation` you need to have a second key( e.g.  kmaterialpart) . This should be same as  `kmaterial` extended by   `'|',   parttypes  '|',  partlocation`

Comment: I have finally had a very close look at this and after a bit of mixing around to make it work in my actual project, the first stage of this answer has definitely solved my dilemma's, I have always had trouble with Key() and trying to understand it a little better. Thanks @hr_117